# What all rules should we follow while declaring the custom methods in a repository?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I was writing custom queries in my Repository which extends JPARepository, when I'm trying to write a inbuilt query and try to run. I'm always unable to get the output. Is there some rules I should follow to get the expected output without errors?

Comment: Please show what you've tried, what was the error and what was the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that would be a pretty vast discussion. But for examples:

All the fetch methods must start with findBy (case-sensitive*). After that we need to give the Entity property name by which we want to fetch the result.

For example:

If we have it in the Entity class, then findByName(String anyName) will work.

But If the Employee Entity does not have property like String name; , and we declare the method findByName, then it will throw an exception.

So, correct property name must be appended to the findBy, in a camelCase fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are several ways to write custom queries:

1. Use camelCase convention for example `findByNameAndSurname(String name, String surname);`
2. Use `@Query` to write custom HQL query like for example - `@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u")`
3. Use Native query like -

   @Query(
   value = "SELECT * FROM USERS u WHERE u.status = 1",
   nativeQuery = true)

But maybe I think, the best would be for you to specify a concrete example with which you are having a problem